# Where are javascripts files saved?

Tags: javascript

Where are they stored - is it in the server or in the browser?

Comment: Tell me where is fancy bred,
Or in the heart or in the head?
How begot, how nourished?
            Reply, reply.

Comment: voting for reopen - don't know why this is closed. it's a very simple question and looks like Syombua doesn't have any idea how websites work - but it's a question that can clearly be answered, like Baramin and others have done.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript files are stored on the server. They're sent to the browser the same way HTML, CSS and image files are sent.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript file are stored on the server when they are used in a web app. You can also store them locally if you want the functionality to reside on your machine or if you are debugging

Answer (score 1):

Well initially on the server and then when you request a page the related scripts are downloaded to your system and executed locally. I am assuming a typical web request response here.

Answer (score 0):

- stored on server
- sent to client (your browser) upon page load
- they can be called from other server (i.e. jQuery libraries from Google) and once again stored on client
- once saved to browser, Javascript files are cached so they aren't loaded from server anymore

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript files are stored on the server and sent to the browser. Only the browser does something with the code. You cannot do something on the server side with JavaScript if you don't have a back end.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on where you put them ... but the browser is out of the question..